# How to separate a dropdown from the page background when it's the same color?

Tags: website-design, critique

To get straight to the point, this is causing trouble:

[image]

The menu on top (work news about media) is a dropdown menu. The problem is that **it has a white background, and the page is also white**, and the text colors match too. This results in a weird, disconcerting and un-esthetic effect when the drop down rolls down over the page contents.

The design is minimalist, uses only two colors and not many elements. This dropdown looks real good on a non-white background, such as [on this page](https://weknowtoomuch.com/projects/nga/).

So, we're pondering ways of separating it from the background.

A border is an obvious solution, another pondered solution is reducing the opacity of the whole page when the dropdown is activated.

Is there any other way?

Edit: Removed the original link because the design is being updated. Will keep you updated...

Answer (score 5):

Agree on the subtle differences. Since your site does not seem to be a fan of drop shadows, i shall only mention that once :-)

Basically, what I would do, is simply play around with inverting the colours you already have. In the case of the dark blue, I would obviously go easy; a same colour a good deal weaker. Here are a few experiments. Pardon the very crude execution, but hope I get the idea across. Please note that these are just general ideas, and does not look very good. If you fiddle with the concept,though, I am sure you will come up with something good.

---

### Dropshadow

[image]

---

### Inverted blue background (colour piced from the "nabil gholam..")

[image]

---

### Inverted with gray picked from other text:

[image]

Comment: I think version 2 or 3 is the way to go. Really makes it pop without disturbing the minimalist feel, and color is much simpler to render than drop shadows. You won't have to worry about whether a browser can pick it up.

Comment: Good point, @LaurenIpsum my sketches are rather inelegant; softer colours would look much better, but it is usually good to work with the elements/colours that are already there.

Answer (score 3):

So I agree, this is obviously a clean design and you don't want to commit to doing anything craaaazy :)

Rather than a full border like you mentioned in your question, why not do something like this?

[image: half border around menu]

Like TunaMaxx said **subtle differences are key**

So the border is only on the left and the bottom and isn't much more than a 2px line, you could use the grey shade that you're using for the text, the blue from the menu or a little darker, either choice should work. The text is a little larger and a little darker. Also around the half border I suggest leaving some white space (maybe 10-15px) that way you won't have any words from the page beneath the menu seeming like they are trying to climb onto it. (as you can see here '2010' is a little close to 'intitutional' this is why I would creat more white space)

There is a little tidying to do there but I think the idea would work.

Just to mention it's still right aligned and stuff in Chrome though I gather from the comments that you already know that.

Good luck with your site :)

Comment: Looks great :) and is also easy to implement.
Regarding Chrome, I'm aware of one issue, I'm not sure it's the one you're mentioning... but in any case cross-browser testing will be done at a later stage. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Design is subjective of course, but for me there is no priority of information. When you open the menu items, there is <strike>nothing</strike> little to differentiate from the base page:

- Font is effectively the same size, color, weight
- Background is the same color
- The menu child items almost align with the underlying grid.

I understand the minimalist, clean approach. As I think you already feel, at least in the menu it has been take too far.

Try:

- *Slightly* different background color on menu child items. We're talking `#eee` versus `#fff`
- *Subtle* box-shadow on menu child items to gently suggest a layer or depth
- Font color something like the active / hover state color
- Some sort of indicator on child items with nested child items.

Answer (score 1):

Did some experimenting myself, taking many of your ideas in consideration (thanks a lot!)

It seems that somehow connecting the submenu with the menu link helps...

[image]

A slight (subtle!) drop shadow could work too...

[image]

Maybe a combination of both?

[image]

It also seems that having only one bold element in the menu (the hovered element) also helps:

[image]

It seems that the problem is not only the backgrounds being confounded, but also that the submenu is (visually) not strongly connected to the menu item.

Answer (score 1):

What happened in the end - and that was a request from the customer, was that we added an overlay on the *whole page* when the menu is visible.

You can see it in action here: http://nabilgholam.com/all-projects  (the website is now live, finally)

I'm even less sure what to pick as accepted answer, now.